# Tensorflow Dataset API shuffle hurts performance by 9x

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the Tensorflow Dataset API to take a bunch of filenames; shuffle the filenames; perform a python function to load the image files, preprocess them, and turn them into tensors; and then cache, repeat, and batch them.  So far, so good.

When I add a `shuffle()` to the tensors, performance degrades by a factor of 9x.  Likewise, when I do `self.dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(16384))`.

**Why does `shuffle` hurt performance so badly, and how can I fix it?**

Code:

```
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(self.FILE_PATTERN).shuffle(buffer_size=16384)
dataset = filenames.map(lambda filename: self.pp(filename), 
num_parallel_calls=self.N_CPUS)
dataset = dataset.cache("./cachefile")
# The line below (shuffle_and_repeat) made performance very bad (1s/step without, 9s/step with)
# dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(16384))
# This too:
# dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(16384)
# This works fine, but doesn't shuffle:
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(self.BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(4)
```

Comment: is there any particular reason you want to shuffle again since you're already shuffling them once?

Comment: For SGD, I'd like it shuffled each epoch; that is, shuffled after the `repeat`.

Comment: I think the problem might be that cache is spilling the data over to disk instead of having it in memory. So it probably reads the cache file and loads it in to memory again and then shuffles and repeats?
have you tried to do shuffle then repeat instead of repeat and then shuffle though the fused operation is supposed to do the same thing?

Comment: Hi is there an answer to this? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the prefetch parameter buffer_size=2

dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)

prefetch is a performance flag, read next number of datasets in background for the next iterations. If prefetch's buffer_size is large, then it creates lots of datasets for iterations and may slow down due to low memory.